# Accessing values from Form in sencha touch

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I am trying to access values from form but I am getting all null values.
My code structure is :
Inside view id is provided say, syzForm
In controller

```
 syzForm:'#syzForm',
```

and trying to access values from form using getter method as `getSyzForm();`

But All values I am getting are null.

Please let me know where I am wrong.

Thanks In advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the config section in your controller make a reference to the form you want to work with.

```
Ext.define('App.controller.Controller', {
extend      : 'Ext.app.Controller',

config  : {
refs: {
        YourFormRef: {
            selector    : 'yourform',
            xtype       : 'yourform',
            autoCreate  : true
        }
}}}
```

And make sure that FormView's id is the same as the selector. Now you should be able use the getters and setters to manipulate your Form.